# Since SE’s decision to put a halt on non-English language based SEs, is linguistics the correct place to put them?

Tags: support

For example, I have seen some questions related to non-English grammar on here come up from time to time. Persian. Turkish etc.

I am learning Turkish and I was wondering if it would be correct to post grammar related questions about the language here or would it be instantly migrated to another SE?

What is your SE’s policy on this?

Comment: There is also [languagelearning.se] but I am afraid that they also don't accept language specific questions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may have misread the concept.

SE is still supporting language sites. Each of these sites [traditionally accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/278208/187133) Q/A written either in English or in the corresponding language. For example, at [Ukrainian Language.SE](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/) you can post in English or Ukrainian.
The site interface, however, (buttons, banners, menus, popups, etc.) is in English.

On the contrary, SE is holding the creation of sites having the entire User Interface (UI) in another language. Check [Stack Overflow in Spanish](https://es.stackoverflow.com/) or [Stack Overflow in Japanese](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/) to see the difference.

Yet another example. There are two sites about the Russian language: [with English UI](https://russian.stackexchange.com/) and [with Russian UI](https://rus.stackexchange.com/), and the quality of posts between the two sites differ drastically. Translation of the UI has never been completed, too:

[image]

SE still supports the creation of language sites of the former kind, but withholds the latter.
So, nothing prevents you from advocating for the creation of Turkish Language.SE.

---

This site, Linguistics.SE, is not actually for asking language-specific grammar or usage questions.

If your question is about the very process of language acquisition — e.g., methodology of teaching and (self-)learning a foreign language — you may ask it at [Language Learning.SE](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Wow, this is good news. I did misunderstand it. Why, have some sites then not done it this way use English as the main communicating point between 2 languages? There was a Turkish language learning site in Area 51 but it was put on hold and was first proposed years ago. Or perhaps because most native Turks do not speak English fluently?

Comment: Thanks for that links! They are useful.

Comment: @aesking, in order to have a successful SE site, it must have a certain "core" of prominent users who actively participate *and* newbies who ask and learn. There's also a threshold of posts per day to consider site alive. Some sites (like [Arabic Language.SE](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/62022/arabic-language)) have been even closed while in Beta due to this reason. So it is not about how many people use Turkish in their life. It is about how many people **actively participate** the Area51 proposal and the newly-created site.

Comment: When I understand correctly, the Arabic Language site became for some reasons impossible to moderate, it was not closed for lack of questions or answers or visits.

Comment: BTW, the Area 51 process was made much more difficult some time ago: You have to get the site through each stage of the process in 4 month instead of 1 year now, and it turns out that getting 100 experienced (i.e. rep >200 on one site) stackexchange users to a new site is difficult even when there are a lot of potential new users around.